# My database detail unable to display in php

Tags: php

This is my code is display my database (member_details) after user sign up but in the database i have a row which is being injected with javascript.

```
    <script>window.location="http://google.com"</script>
```

it redirect user to google.com when i view the script in browser.

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      include ('includes/database_connection.inc.php');
    $conn = connectDatabase();

      if($_SESSION['uid'] == ''){
        // redirect unauthenticate user to login page.
      header('Location: login.php');
      }

      if($_GET['task'] == 'delete' && $_GET['id'] != ''){
          // delete function here
         $sql="DELETE FROM Newest Where ID='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'";

         mysql_query($sql,$conn);
         header('Location: member_list.php');
      }

      if($_POST['Logout']){
         session_destroy();
       header('Location: login.php');
    }

    ?>

    <html><head><title>Member Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style=" margin: 350px ">
    <?php


          $sql="SELECT * FROM Newest";
          $rs = mysql_query($sql,$conn)
            or die( mysql_error() );


       $list = "<table border=\"1\" cellpadding= \"2\">";
       $list .= "<tr><th>First Name</th>";
       $list .="<th>Last Name</th>";
       $list .= "<th>User Name</th>";
       $list .= "<th>Email</th>";
       $list .= "<th>Edit User</th>";
       $list .= "<th>Delete User</th>";
        $list .= "<th>Change Password</th>";


    While( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs) ) {

        $list .= "<tr>";
        $list .= "<td>".$row["name"]."</td>";
         $list .= "<td>".$row["last"]."</td>";
        $list .= "<td>".$row["user"]."</td>";
        $list .= "<td>".$row["email"]."</td>";
        $list .= "<td><a href='member_details.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>Edit</a></td>";
        $list .= "<td><a onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure to delete ".$row["name"]." \")' href='member_list.php?id=".$row["ID"]."&task=delete'>Delete</a></td>";
         $list .= "<td><a  href='Password.php?id=".$row['ID']."'>Click Here</a></td>
         </tr>";

    }
       $list .= "</table>";
       echo ( $list );

    ?>
       <form method="post" action="member_list.php"><br>
       <div style="margin : 0px 600px">
       <style type="text/css">
    body {background:#F5F5F5 url('http://images.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/travel/images/traveltodolist_20070724165034.jpg') no-repeat top;;

           }</style>


             <input type="submit" name="Logout" value="logout" />

          </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Make your data safe when you're outputting it - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter your data before inserting it to database. Basic one is using: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

While fetching your records from database use: [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

so that such tags are stripped off.
Hope it helps